# third level of CSS dropdown menu not appearing in two-column format

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have constructed a three-level dropdown using CSS. It works until I add this to the CSS:

```
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
```

The HTML is basically just two unordered lists (by the way, the "feelings" list and the "needs" list have the same content -- that will change eventually -- this is just for experimenting!):

```
<div class="feelings">
<ul class="nav feelings">
  <li class="feelings" id="feelings"> FEELINGS
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">AFRAID</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">apprehensive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dread</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">foreboding</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">frightened</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">mistrustful</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">panicked</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">petrified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">scared</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">suspicious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">terrified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">wary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">worried</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ANNOYED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">aggravated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dismayed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disgruntled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">displeased</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">exasperated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">frustrated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">impatient</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irritated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irked</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ANGRY</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">enraged</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">furious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">incensed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">indignant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">livid</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">outraged</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">resentful</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">AVERSION</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">animosity</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">appalled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contempt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disgusted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dislike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">horrified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hostile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">repulsed</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONFUSED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ambivalent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">baffled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bewildered</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dazed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hesitant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">lost</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">mystified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">perplexed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">puzzled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">torn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DISCONNECTED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">alienated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">aloof</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">apathetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bored</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cold</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">detached</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distracted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">indifferent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">numb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">removed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">uninterested</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">withdrawn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DISQUIET</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">agitated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">alarmed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">discombobulated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disconcerted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disturbed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">perturbed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">rattled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">restless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">shocked</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">startled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">surprised</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">troubled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">turbulent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">turmoil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">uncomfortable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">uneasy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">unnerved</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">unsettled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">upset</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">EMBARRASSED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ashamed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">chagrined</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">flustered</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">guilty</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">mortified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">self-conscious</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">FATIGUE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">beat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">burnt out</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">depleted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">exhausted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">lethargic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">listless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sleepy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">tired</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">weary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">worn out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PAIN</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">agony</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">anguished</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bereaved</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">devastated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">grief</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">heartbroken</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hurt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">lonely</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">miserable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">regretful</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">remorseful</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">SAD</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">depressed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dejected</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">despair</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">despondent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disappointed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">discouraged</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disheartened</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">forlorn</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">gloomy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">heavy hearted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hopeless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">melancholy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">unhappy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">wretched</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">TENSE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">anxious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cranky</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distressed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distraught</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">edgy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">fidgety</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">frazzled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irritable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jittery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">nervous</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">overwhelmed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">restless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">stressed out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">VULNERABLE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">fragile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">guarded</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">helpless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">insecure</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">leery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">reserved</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sensitive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">shaky</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">YEARNING</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">envious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jealous</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">longing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">nostalgic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">pining</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">wistful</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="needs">
<ul class="nav needs">
  <li class="feelings" id="needs"> NEEDS    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">AFRAID</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">apprehensive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dread</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">foreboding</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">frightened</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">mistrustful</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">panicked</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">petrified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">scared</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">suspicious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">terrified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">wary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">worried</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ANNOYED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">aggravated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dismayed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disgruntled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">displeased</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">exasperated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">frustrated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">impatient</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irritated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irked</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ANGRY</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">enraged</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">furious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">incensed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">indignant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">livid</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">outraged</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">resentful</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">AVERSION</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">animosity</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">appalled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contempt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disgusted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dislike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">horrified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hostile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">repulsed</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONFUSED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ambivalent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">baffled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bewildered</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dazed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hesitant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">lost</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">mystified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">perplexed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">puzzled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">torn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DISCONNECTED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">alienated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">aloof</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">apathetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bored</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cold</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">detached</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distracted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">indifferent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">numb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">removed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">uninterested</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">withdrawn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DISQUIET</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">agitated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">alarmed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">discombobulated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disconcerted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disturbed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">perturbed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">rattled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">restless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">shocked</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">startled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">surprised</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">troubled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">turbulent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">turmoil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">uncomfortable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">uneasy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">unnerved</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">unsettled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">upset</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">EMBARRASSED</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ashamed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">chagrined</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">flustered</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">guilty</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">mortified</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">self-conscious</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">FATIGUE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">beat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">burnt out</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">depleted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">exhausted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">lethargic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">listless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sleepy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">tired</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">weary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">worn out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PAIN</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">agony</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">anguished</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bereaved</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">devastated</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">grief</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">heartbroken</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hurt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">lonely</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">miserable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">regretful</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">remorseful</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">SAD</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">depressed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dejected</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">despair</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">despondent</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disappointed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">discouraged</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">disheartened</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">forlorn</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">gloomy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">heavy hearted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hopeless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">melancholy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">unhappy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">wretched</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">TENSE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">anxious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cranky</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distressed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">distraught</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">edgy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">fidgety</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">frazzled</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">irritable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jittery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">nervous</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">overwhelmed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">restless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">stressed out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">VULNERABLE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">fragile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">guarded</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">helpless</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">insecure</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">leery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">reserved</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sensitive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">shaky</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">YEARNING</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">envious</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jealous</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">longing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">nostalgic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">pining</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">wistful</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

ul ul, ul ul ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}

 .nav feelings needs {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    color:#ff0000;  
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.nav{
    height: 39px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-width:500px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}   

.nav li, .nav li li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;  
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.nav a {
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nav li a{
    display: block;
}

.nav ul {
    display: none;
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}

.nav ul ul {
    top: 0px;
    left:170px;
    display: none;
    visibility:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    position: relative;
}


.nav ul li {
    display: block;
    visibility:visible;
}
.nav li:hover > ul, nav li:hover * {
    display: block;
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:1;
}
```

If I eliminate the first CSS item (setting the menu to two columns), the last level of the menu appears (the items in small letters as opposed to all caps).  With the two-column CSS in place, the third level doesn't appear.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7NK/2/

Interestingly, on the fiddle, the third level does seem to be trying to appear a bit, but it's certainly not working the way I'd like it to, which is the third level appearing in a vertical column to the right of the second level item.

Any thoughts will be appreciated!

/*** image below was added after original question, in response to a request for a picture ***/

The top screenshot in this picture shows what comes up now when I hover over the first feeling, AFRAID -- and it is actually pretty much what I want (though obviously it needs some prettifying): two sets of two-column dropdowns, namely, the one in all caps and the one in all  small letters.  (This is basically with the code shown above, but with one change, namely, removing **ul ul** to leave only **ul ul ul** as suggested by user3369554.) However, when I move the cursor, stuff starts jumping all over the place; the screenshot on the bottom shows one state, but things just jump all over in a very disconcerting way. For instance, I would like to be able to just move the cursor over to where ANGRY is at the top of the second column. But if I try to do that, it jumps to somewhere else. And if I go to that place, it jumps to still another location. If the both sets of emotions (all caps and all small letters) would hold still in the configuration shown at the top, and let me click on them, I'd be happy.
[image: top shows how I'd like it to work]

Comment: You don't really need to be using `display:none` AND `visibility:hidden`. I'd just use `display:none` for hiding and `display:block|inline|inline-block|etc` for showing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding well, but you can get the third level in a 2 column format to the right of the second level, if you replace:

```
ul ul, ul ul ul
```

for

```
ul ul ul
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QKkg4/

Is that what your're after?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, user3369554.  That is closer than anything I achieved. At least all three levels are showing up! However, the second level is rather "jumpy". For example, when the cursor is on AFRAID, ANGRY is to the right of ANNOYED. When I moved the cursor to ANNOYED, ANGRY moves underneath ANNOYED. If I could just get the items on level two to stand still after they appear, I think I might be close to what I'm looking for. I've tried various **position** attributes (e.g. **position:absolute**), but no joy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle? or an image, nothing fancy, just blocks of text of your intended effect?

Comment: Please see the image I added at the end of my original post above, along with some commentary! And thanks again for your help!Please see the image I added at the end of my original post above, along with some commentary! And thanks again for your help!